# How can I switch from a fragment to another fragment in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want the fragment_yetki.xml file to be opened when the yetki_modulu_cardView in the fragment_mudur_home.xml is clicked. How can I do this from within the MudurHomeFragment.kt class?

[MudurHomeFragment.kt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy4qE.png)

[fragment_home_mudur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dohSK.png)

Comment: Are you using the navigation component? That has become the recommended way of managing your Fragments and navigating between them. https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that first you have to create an action in the mobile_navigation page.
Like this

```
`<fragment
        android:id="@+id/titleFragment"
        android:name="com.dheeraj.guessbro.title.TitleFragment"
        android:label="title_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/title_fragment">
       **<action
            android:id="@+id/action_titleFragment_to_gameFragment"
            app:destination="@id/gameFragment" />**
    </fragment>'
```

and then go to the MudurHomeFragment.kt file and just use this code :

**binding.yetki_modulu_cardView.setOnClickListener {          findNavController(this).navigate(R.id.action_titleFragment_to_gameFragment)
}**

If you are not using view binding then you can first define the variable using findViewById and then use the clickListener.